# Boost statechart interaction

Tags: c++, boost, boost-statechart

I have two statecharts (FSM_A and FSM_B) implemented using boost::statechart.

Is it safe to process an event from FSM_A in order to trigger a transition in FSM_B?

Should I use two async_state_machine? Or maybe a common outermost state?

Here is an example:

```
struct FSM_B;

struct FSM_A : sc::state_machine<FSM_A, InitialStateA>
{
    FSM_B* pB;
};

struct FSM_B : sc::state_machine<FSM_B, InitialStateB>
{};

struct InitialStateB : sc::simple_state<InitialStateB, FSM_B>
{
    typedef sc::transition< EV_CrossEvent, InitialStateB > rections;
};

struct InitialStateA : sc::simple_state<InitialStateA, FSM_A>
{
    InitialStateA()
    {
        context<FSM_A>().pB->process_event( EV_CrossEvent() );
    }
};

int main()
{
    FSM_B b;
    FSM_A a;
    a.pB = &b;

    a.initiate();
    b.initiate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically, you can do that. Whether this's a correct design or not - depends on the problem you attempt to solve.

Comment: @Igor Thanks. My concern is about the dynamic cast involved in performing the process_event (since we are in a constructor there).

Comment: a common outermost context. This will be the best